# Make a call, than wait for the robot, then enter a code for activation

Tags: java, android

I have an activation code, and a number to call.

How can I call the number, than enter the code for activation automatically via the Android SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, except maybe in speakerphone mode via `ToneGenerator`. Beyond speakerphone mode, you have no access to the in-call audio stream.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, with my user head on, I'd be very nervous about an app doing this anyway.

I'd say the best approach to use here is to set up a SMS gateway to receive a SMS from the phone, or a HTTP request.

Failing that, you might be able to set the dialled number to include pauses to allow time for the remote end to answer - inserting 'p', 'w', or ',' between the number and the activation code.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello